# How to return response after start event in Flowable with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flowable

I start my flowable process by calling startProcessInstanceByMessage with variables as parameter. After that process starts and all service task are called. 
When process ends I get response with variable.

I don't want to wait until process ends with response. It may tooks ages and client can't wait. What I want is eg. processId variable returned after process starts and all other tasks should run in background without client awaiting. 
[image]

As it is presented above, I want response from my REST Api after Start event, before Task 1. 
Task 1 to N should work in background.

I tried to use asynchronous flag in XML configuration of BPMN in flowable.
Unfortunately in my service tasks I use beans with @Autowire. After calling process I get exception

```
No thread-bound request found: 
Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request
```

Any advice how to get response after start event and continue tasks without client awaiting for response?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to run Task 1, Task 2, etc. in the background you need to set the `asynchronous` flag on the first task.

I don't know what you are using from the service task (`expression`, `delegateExpression`, `class` ). If you are using Spring then using `class` is not recommended. You should either use `expression` and call methods on your bean or use `delegateExpression` and make your bean implement `JavaDelegate`.